# Java Comparable return value, does it have to be exactly 1, -1 or 0?

Tags: java, comparable

This might be a trivial question, but I have not found anything about it, so here goes:
When implementing the [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, we are supposed to define the method `compareTo()`, so that the following is true according to the documentation:

> - sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compareTo(x)) for all x and y.
> - The relation is transitive: (x.compareTo(y)>0 && y.compareTo(z)>0) implies x.compareTo(z)>0.
> - x.compareTo(y)==0 implies that sgn(x.compareTo(z)) ==    sgn(y.compareTo(z)), for all z.

Now, the part that gets confusing is the return value, that is specified as follows:

> Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object
>   is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

It seems that most implementations return `1`, `-1` or `0`, even though it is not mentioned as a requirement that the return value is limited in this way.
The following code thus works for Sorting a list (using `Collections.sort()`) containing instances of a class, `Foo`:

```
public int compareTo(Foo other){
    return this.value > other.value? 1 : this.value < other.value ? -1 : 0;
}
```

This however do not:

```
public int compareTo(Foo other){
    return (int)(this.value - other.value);
}
```

Where `value` is a `long`, and the difference between the values do not exceed `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Am I missing something here, or is the return value required to be exactly `1`, `-1` or `0`, contradictory to the documentation?

**Update:** Thanks for all your answers, but it seems that the human factor was to blame here. I mentioned that the calculated difference was less than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which should mean that there is no overflow, but my calculations were wrong, so *I did actually get overflow*, which caused the strange results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The contract was so flexible to allow `this.value - other.value` idioms (which later turned out to be incorrect due to integer overflow). But in some cases it is still valueable, like `str.length() - str2.length()`. It is <del>unlikely</del> impossible that string or array size comparison will overflow since the minimum length is 0 and the maximum is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (`0 - Integer.MAX_VALUE` is still greater than `Integer.MIN_VALUE`) so it is convenient when you need to sort by length/size.

Also comparing to 0 (greater-than/less-than) is often faster/genrates smaller bytecode/assembly than comparing to 1/-1, so why limit the users? You are absolutely free to use any positive/negative value.

Comment: There is no such a limitation, you can return any negative or positive integer you want, refer to Effective Java.

Comment: Marked this as the solution as it was what led me to find the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you can return any integer you want. What exactly is the error you are getting?

Please test the following class:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

        final ToSort sort0 = new ToSort(-100);
        final ToSort sort1 = new ToSort(1);
        final ToSort sort2 = new ToSort(100);


        List<ToSort> elements = new ArrayList<ToSort>(){{add(sort2); add(sort1); add(sort0);}};
        System.out.println("Unsorted:" + elements.toString());

        Collections.sort(elements);

        System.out.println("Sorted:" + elements.toString());

    }

    static class ToSort implements Comparable{

        long value;
        public ToSort(long value){
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Object other) {
            return (int) (this.value - ((ToSort)other).value);
        }

        public String toString(){
            return ""+value;
        }
    }
```

I get the following output:

```
run:
Unsorted:[100, 1, -100]
Sorted:[-100, 1, 100] 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

You might want to add a breakpoint in your `compareTo` method and debug to check if you are running what you are expecting.

Comment: No error, the list is just not sorted property. The double return was a copy-paste mistake.

Comment: `new Long(1).longValue()` is `1L` so `(int)(new Long(1).longValue() - other)` is `1 - (int) other`

Comment: @PeterLawrey indeed it is, that was just for demonstration purposes - already edited, but `(int) (long-long)` gives the same results as `((int) long) - ((int) long)`, right?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the problem I was experiencing was due to the large difference between the long-values causing integer overflow.

Comment: @Jave Can you give an example of this? I am betting you can't. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Seems you win the bet. I thought that casting a long to integer (or any other primitive cast to fewer bits) just truncated the results. Learning so much today! :p

Answer (score -1):

Javadocs also say:

> In the foregoing description, the notation sgn(expression) designates the mathematical signum function, **which is defined to return one of -1, 0, or 1** according to whether the value of expression is negative, zero or positive.

EDIT:

Yes, i misunderstood. you are right.

Comment: Yes, but it is never mentioned that you have to use `sgn` on the result.